# How to add leading zeroes to Dataframe column if value is an integer, conditional on another column's values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

Is there an efficient way to add leading zeroes to a Dataframe's columns if:

1. The column contains integer values, and
2. For a given value of another column in the same Dataframe

E.g. for the following Dataframe, how do I create a new DataFrame that has leading zeroes in values in `col_2` if:

1. `col_2` are integer values (i.e. not `"text"` nor `"text2"`)
2. `col_1 == "A"`

Initial Dataframe:

```py
col_1   col_2
0   A   12345
1   B   863
2   A   text
3   C   893423
4   D   text2
```

Desired output Dataframe:

```py
col_1   col_2
0   A   00012345
1   B   863
2   A   text
3   C   893423
4   D   text2
```

Comment: what do you want to do once you identify which rows have A and a numeric/integer value in col_2?

Comment: I want to be able to use `zfill` to add starting zeroes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `to_numeric` with `errors="coerce"` to ensure values are numeric:

```
# is the value numeric?
m1 = pd.to_numeric(df['col_2'], errors='coerce').notna()
# is col_1 equal to "A"?
m2 = df['col_1'].eq('A')

# pick the rows matching both conditions
# and do something with it
df[m1&m2]
```

If you want to ensure having integers and not any numerical value (i.e. floating points), you can use:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df['col_2'], errors='coerce')
# is a numeric value and an integer
m1 = s.notna() & s.eq(s.round())
```

##### zfilling

```
m1 = pd.to_numeric(df['col_2'], errors='coerce').notna()
m2 = df['col_1'].eq('A')

df.loc[m1&m2, 'col_2'] = df.loc[m1&m2, 'col_2'].astype(str).str.zfill(8)
```

output:

```
  col_1     col_2
0     A  00012345
1     B       863
2     A      text
3     C    893423
4     D     text2
```

Comment: added an option to zfill the numeric values that have A in col_1

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want :

```
df[df['col_1']=='A'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, int) )
```

Output :

```
col_1    False
col_2    False
```

Comment: if I want to edit `df` inplace, do I just add a `df = ` in front of that, or would that reduce my `df` down to only the Output?

Comment: it would indeed reduce your df, can you show me your desired output? i would be happy to help

Comment: thanks @grymlin - have added to the initial question